# What is in practice an anticausal filter?

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform, discrete-calculus

Could someone enlighten me about anticausal filters?
Actually, I'm trying to understand why the function
$\dfrac{1}{1-az}$ is the transfer function of a first order anticausal filter.

I think I understood why $\dfrac{1}{1-az^{-1}}$ is the transfer function of a first order causal filter : a first order causal filter is given by
$$
y(n) = x(n) + ay(n-1)
$$
and hence we can compute the output recursively and we obtain the impulse response $a^nu(n)$. Then the z-transform of this function is indeed $\dfrac{1}{1-az^{-1}}$.

But now for the anticausal filter I'm having doubts. A first order anticausal filter is given by $y(n) = x(n) + ay(n+1)$, right? Then how can I compute the outputs? Am I supposed to have an initial condition for some indice K and then applying the recursion in the decreasing way? Could someone give an example? I feel lost because it's the reverse case of the causal filter. And how can I get to the transfer function $\dfrac{1}{1-az}$?

Thanks a lot!

Marie

Comment: The thing about anti causal or non-causal in general is that you have to "wait" until you have enough samples to apply it. That is you get kind of a "delay" before you can get the output from the filter. The first order one gives a delay of one sample and longer delay the higher the order.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I don't see how to proceed in practice. In my case I'm not dealing with time because I'm working with image processing, so my "times" are actually grid points. Then how to get to the transfer function that I mentionned?

Comment: Yes your filter is an IIR filter so it's "memory" or "delay" is in practice infinite due to the geometric series expansion being infinite but exponentially decreasing amplitude. If it was a anticausal FIR filter then it would be as i wrote delay of a number of samples.

Comment: In image processing there are many ways to try and "extend" signals to make the filter taps get something to work on. Mirroring, polynomial expansion, border expansion, zero padding, assuming periodic image ( wrap around ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_filter),

> A causal filter is a filter whose output depends only on past and present
>   inputs.

The filter described by the difference equation 
$$
\tag{1}
y[n] = x[n] + ay[n+1],
$$
is *not* causal. Indeed, by repeated use of $(1)$, one can write

$$
\begin{align}
y[n] &=x[n]+a(x[n+1]+ay[n+2])\\
&=x[n]+ax[n+1]+a^2y[n+2]\\
&=x[n]+ax[n+1]+a^2(x[n+2]+ay[n+3])\\
&=\cdots\\
\tag{2}
&=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}a^lx[n+l],
\end{align}
$$
i.e., the output at time $n$ depends on current and *future* input values. Equivalently, one can show that the impulse response of the system is

$$
h[n]=a^{-n}u[-n]
$$

which has non-zero elements for $n<0$, whereas a causal impulse response has non-zero elements only for $n\geq0$.

Now, it may appear that a non-causal filter is only a mathematical concept with no practical implementation as "one needs to know the future". In practice, a non-causal filter is implemented by introducing a sufficiently large delay. In particular, the system buffers the signal values $x[n],x[n+1],x[n+2],\cdots, x[n+D]$ where $D>0$ is the *delay* and computes the output $y[n]$ as $y[n]=\sum_{l=0}^{D}a^lx[n+l]$.

Note that with this approach:

1. The output $y[n]$ is computed when the signal $x[n+D]$ is available, i.e., the output is generated with a delay of $D$ samples.
2. From $(2)$, the output at a certain instant depends on *all* future input samples. For practical reasons, we have to consider only a finite number (equal to $D$) of future input samples. Therefore the value of $D$ not only affects the delay of the output but also the computation accuracy (larger $D$ will provide a more accurate approximation of the output, however, with a cost of increased delay).

Comment: Very clear answer, thanks! I just have a little further question : can an anticausal filter depend on present and future inputs or only future inputs? I.e., is the filter (1) just non causal or also anticausal?

Comment: @MarieC This is a matter of definition. In my mind there are two types of filters: causal and non-causal. As long as a filter depends on a future input (possibly also depending on present and/or past values as well), it is a non-causal filter. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_filter) article states that an *anti-causal* filter is a filter which *depends only on future inputs*. I guess this makes sense as the term "anti-" in anti-causal suggests that the filter has the opposite properties of the causal filter which depends on past and present input.